# $wp_customizer T.Variable Error (Wordpress Theme Customizer)

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have this piece of code :

```
<?php
    function mytheme_register_theme_customizer( $wp_customizer ){_

    $wp_customizer->add_section(
        'display_option' ,
        array(
            'title'     => 'Display Options',
            'priority'  => 200

            )
    );

    $wp_customizer->add_setting(
            'index_background_image' ,
            array(
                    'default'   => '' ,
                    'transport' => 'postMessage'
                )

        );

    $wp_customizer->add_control(
        new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
            $wp_customizer,
            'index_background_image',
            array(

                    'label'     => 'Background Image',
                    'section'   => 'display_options',
                    'settings'  => 'background_image'
                )
            )
        );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_register_theme_customizer' );

?>
```

And all I get as a result, at localhost in my browser is :

" *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$wp_customizer' (T_VARIABLE) in D:\Desktop v2\XAMPP\htdocs\wp-content\themes\reconsider\functions.php on line 50* "

Where Line 50 is :

```
$wp_customizer->add_section(
```

Sadly I can't see my syntax mistake.

**All my directories are listed as mytheme.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the underscore from the end of this line:

```
function mytheme_register_theme_customizer( $wp_customizer ){_
```

so it becomes:

```
function mytheme_register_theme_customizer( $wp_customizer ){
```

Comment: Oh my god. It was purple color so i couldn't even see it. Thank you sir and have a nice day!